# C++ Extract std::string from a variable-length argument list

Tags: c++, string, variadic-functions

Hey everyone! I'm trying to make a simple copy of sprintf that returns the formatted string, but I am coming into a small snag...

Apparently, using a variable-length argument list you cannot pass a std::string instance.

I already have the parser working properly with int, double, float, char, const char*, char*... I have yet to get strings to work. :\

In case you're wondering, this is the compile error I get: `/root/learncpp/StringFormat/main.cpp:8: warning: cannot pass objects of non-POD type 'struct std::string' through '...'; call will abort at runtime`

The main reason I'm doing this is so that I can have convenient formatting without having to rely on 3rd party libraries, yet still not have to append ".c_str()" to **every** string instance I use.

Help with this would be appreciated. Perhaps there's a different version of variable-length argument lists made specifically for C++?

EDIT: I have just realized, if you pass a pointer to a string (i.e. using the & prefix) it works well. All you have to do is dereference a string pointer in the custom sprintf, while passing the address of the std::string!

Still, it would be nice to see if there's any way to support string directly through variable-length argument lists. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No -- as the compiler said, you're only allowed to pass objects of POD type to a variadic function.

What you normally want to do is eliminate using a variadic function in the first place, such as by using an iostream instead of something like printf (or a stringstream instead of sprintf).

Comment: Well, the reason I like sprintf is the way you can automatically convert ints/doubles into a string, and the nice format of using it. iostreams/stringstreams just seem clumsy to me when it's mixing many variables and spacers, i.e. "Hello %s, the time is %d:%d:%d, on the %dth day of the %dth month."

Comment: Have you looked at Boost format? http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/format/index.html

Comment: @Jerry, isn't boost hard to get working at times? I've seen several people having a hard time to get it to link or compile (can't remember which) properly

Comment: @FurryHead:  The simplest way to use a stringstream for trivial conversions is to use `boost::lexical_cast`; it is straightforward to implement and you can find the basic implementation in Herb Sutter's article, ["The String Formatters of Manor Farm"](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill19.htm)

Comment: Some parts of Boost can be hard to build, but if I'm not mistaken, Boost Format is a header-only library, so all you have to do is include the header(s) you need.

Comment: @FurryHead: os << "Hello" << name << ", the time is " << hour << ':' << min << ':' << sec << ", on the " << day << "th day of the " << month << "th month."; Easy.

Comment: @Jerry, great! Offhand, do you know if I would be able to distribute it included in my software?

Comment: @Johnsyweb, but which LOOKS better? `printf("Hello %s, the time is %d:%d:%d, on the %dth day of the %dth month.", name, hour, minute, second, day, month);` or your example? To me, printf() is more readable most of the time.

Comment: @FurryHead: I would say the streams version is easier to read and far, far easier to maintain as everything is inline.

Comment: @FurryHead: yes -- the Boost license is *quite* liberal. It basically says you get no warranty of any kind, and if you distribute source code, you need to keep their license/copyright in it. As far as distributing compiled programs go, it's about the same as if you'd written it all yourself (doesn't even require attribution, though I'd certainly give it). See: http://www.boost.org/users/license.html

Comment: @Johnsyweb: and then you get a French (me) who asks you to translates the text, and suddenly IOStreams are no longer convenient, at all.

Comment: @Matthieu: that is an excellent point. At that juncture I'd look to Boost for my string formatting. Until then YAGNI.

Comment: @Jonhsyweb: YAGNI indeed, I use streams for logging ;)